# Найти физические адреса

Tags: ассемблер

В вычислительной системе с сегментной организацией памяти из 32-х бит адреса старшие 14 его бит отводятся для номера сегмента. Для некоторого процесса таблица сегментов в этой системе имеет вид:

```
номер сегмента, адрес начала, длина
1               0х00000       0х8000
2               0х20000       0х2000
3               0х10000       0х10000
5               0х30000       0х0f000.
```

Какому физическому адресу соответствует адрес 0х45678?

Друзья, скажите, пожалуйста, что делать. Прочитал учебник - легче не стало.

Comment: А это точно все задание и правильно ли вы его переписали?

Comment: да, все так. Только что перепроверил

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Логический адрес 0х45678 имеет 1 в поле сегмента и 
0х5678 в поле смещения.

Понять это мы можем переведя 0х45678 в двоичный вид `0000 0000 0000 0100 0101 0110 0111 1000` первые 14 бит будут номером сегмента (`0000 0000 0000 01`) остальное смещением (`00 0101 0110 0111 1000` или 0x5678)

Для получения физического адреса надо к адресу начала сегмента прибавить смещение.

Для получения адреса начала сегмента надо воспользоваться таблицей.
Мы знаем что наш логический адрес содержит 1 в поле номера сегмента.
Из таблице видно (см первую строку таблици) что соответствующий сегмент имеет адрес начала равный нулю.

Складываем адрес начала сегмента 0х00000 с 0х5678 и получаем физический адрес

Comment: скажите, пожалуйста, из каких соображений мы получаем 1 и 5678?

Comment: Я в затруднении. Прям не знаю что и ответить. В задании сказано что числа у нас 32 битные и первые 14 бит это номер сегмента. Что именно вам не понятно?

Comment: физ адрес складывается из номера сегмента, для которого отведено 14 бит, адреса начала и смещения, если я правильно понимаю. Я не очень понимаю, как вы из логического таким образом находите физический

Comment: Я думаю что вам стоит перечитать учебник потому что объяснения содержащиеся в нем лучше моих. Но всеже попробую улучшить мой ответ.

Comment: Я почти все понял. Только первая цифра 1 не очень понял, откуда берется?

Comment: Думаю что стоит ознакомится с разделом об двоичном представлении чисел. Добавил пояснения в ответ

Comment: понял. Большое спасибо, что помогли разобраться. Оказалось, все элементарно!